# Which word to use, "again" or "anymore"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english

I'd like to describe an action which I'm used to do but I won't do it in the future. Which word is correct, for example:

```
Just a little more work, I'll never need that tool again.
```

Or:

```
Just a little more work, I'll never need that tool anymore.
```

If there is any better way to describe it, please help me to correct my sentence, too.

Comment: Regardless of the choice between *again* and *anymore*, there is the issue that the whole sentence is awkward, perhaps verging on incorrect. It seems to me that what you're trying to say would sound better with the comma replaced by *and*: "Just a little more work and I'll never need that tool again." Depending on your actual meaning, you might instead insert *after* or *with* at the beginning: "With just a little more work, I'll never need that tool again."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some confusion among learners on how to use: *again* and *anymore* but specifically more so  with: *anymore*. Perhaps the first being its orthography, [**anymore**](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/adjectives-and-adverbs/13/anymore-vs-any-more/) can also be written formally as: **any more**. Only recently has the one word version gained acceptance. Secondly, in some parts of the US it is found in [**positive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_anymore) sentences such as :"Anymore we watch videos rather than go to the movies." However, (I believe) it is very uncommon in the UK and the majority of grammar books would advise against using this construction.

**Meanings**

*Anymore* means the same as *any longer* and *nowadays*. These first two expressions are interchangeable, and the meaning will remain the same.

- "She's always out with her boyfriend, she hardly meets her old friends any longer/nowadays."
- "She's always out with her boyfriend, she hardly meets her old friends anymore."
- "Just a little more work, I *won't* need that tool any longer"
- "Just a little more work, I *won't* need that tool anymore."

However, due to the repetition of the word "more", the last sentence sounds clumsy and awkward. Choosing *any longer* will avoid this minor inaesthetic construction.

Note: I removed the negative meaning adverb, never, in order to make the sentences flow more naturally.

**again** = once more, another time.

- "Just a little more work"

is grammatically correct and acceptable in writing but *sounds* slightly stiff in the context of everyday speech. If your aim is to sound more natural try: "*a little bit*" (a very common colloquial expression).

- "never need that tool again"

is a very strong statement allowing no leeway; however, speakers sometimes interject `ever` before `again` to add a touch of humour and/or extra emphasis.

- Just a little bit more work, then I'll never need that tool *ever*
  again.

  If I were the speaker and I had been using a tool for a certain length of time I might consider superfluous the word, work, and instead *say* something similar to:

> Just a little bit more, then I'll never use that tool again.

or

> I just need to use that tool for a little bit more, then I won't be
>   needing it again.

or (with *work*)

> Just a little bit more work and then I won't need it any longer

Comment: _Any( )more_ is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) and has its own idiomatic syntax within the [NPI](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) system. Its meaning is complex and involves [presuppositions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Presuppositiontriggers.pdf) and change of state, and it can only occur in a negative environment.

Comment: +1 Very detailed & helpful answer. As a Brit, I've never heard of the 'positive' usage of 'anymore'.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about positive _anymore_. It's a rare example of generalization; from a strictly negative-polarity [+p _=ᵗ=>_ -p] it's now gone to a fully commutative [±p _=ᵗ=>_ ∓p].

Comment: @TrevorD: Even in those parts of the U.S. that the positive *anymore* is used at all, I don't think it's particularly common. (It's uncommon enough that I can't even identify which parts of the U.S. use it. I've never heard it in my life, and I've been all over the country.)

Comment: @PeterShor on the wiki link it states "with a meaning similar to nowadays or from now on".

Answer (score 3):

In this sentence, use *again*. If you'd like to use *anymore*, say, "I will not need that tool anymore."

Comment: This assumes the " 'anymore' is a valid word" stance. There is a debate on this issue eloquently set out at http://alt-usage-english.org/anymore.html .

Comment: But assuming you DO fall in the camp that suggest that anymore means "nowadays" or "any longer", then it is correct

Comment: But assuming you DON'T ...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem right to use *anymore* in that way

So if you have a sentence like this

> Just a little more work, I'll never need that tool again.

If you want to use *anymore* instead of *again* I would recommend replacing *I'll never* with *I won't*

> Just a little more work, I won't need that tool anymore.